# Celery (django) and Rabbit, high number of queue created

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I've been having trouble with the celery and rabbitmq. If i open the stats, i see this:

[image]

and

[image]

If i get it right, right now I've 15K queues, how is that possible?

is it possible that due to some missconfigurations it creates a queue every message?
is that the case?
in the code there's a lot of `apply_async`, can be that that he generates a random queue everytime?
is there a way to know what the queues are or who have created them?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. The queue are results from celery.

this is what we had in `django`

```
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'
```

altought `CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True` the results are sent since `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'` is set.

by removing `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` it stopped to create queues.